# Multiple green lines in Htop: what do they mean?

Tags: ubuntu, htop

htop gives unlimited multiple green lines under white line on linux.

What do multiple green lines mean?

And how can I prevent it?

It seems that each takes a certain amount of memory

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They're threads belonging to a parent (white) process.

You can toggle display of *user* threads on and off in `htop` with the <kbd>H</kbd> key.  That's a capital "H", not lowercase.

Similarly, <kbd>K</kbd> toggles display of *kernel* threads on and off.

BTW, you can get help in `htop` by pressing <kbd>?</kbd> or <kbd>h</kbd> or <kbd>F1</kbd>.